# Knockoutjs - Template with dynamic variables

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm learning javascript and ko by trying my hand at a character sheet for my favorite tabletop rpg.  Since this is day 3, I'm not even sure I'm approaching this correctly, but below is my attempt at producing a form for skills.  It produces no errors, but also has zero functionality.

The evals are my attempt to produce a reference to other observables/computed observables, but no luck.  The $data part of the eval was a later addition of an interpretation of advice on how to correct the problem.

```
<script type="text/html" id="skills-template">
    <div data-bind="template: { name: 'skills-template', foreach: skills }"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1" data-bind="text: skill"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"><strong data-bind="text: eval('$data.' + skill + 'Total')"></strong></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"><input size="2" data-bind="textInput: eval('$data.' + skill + 'Ranks')" /></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"><strong data-bind="text: eval('$data.' + skillMod)"></strong></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"><input size="2" data-bind="textInput: eval('$data.' + skill + 'Mod')" /></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"><strong data-bind="text: untrained"></strong></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">&nbsp;</div> 
    </div>

</script>
```

For reference, here is the skills obj I created.

```
self.skills = [
    { skill: 'Acrobatics', skillMod: 'dexMod', untrained: 'Yes', acPenalty: 'Yes' },
    { skill: 'Appraise', skillMod: 'Dex', untrained: 'Yes', acPenalty: 'No' },
    { skill: 'Bluff', skillMod: 'Dex', untrained: 'Yes', acPenalty: 'No' },
    { skill: 'Climb', skillMod: 'Dex', untrained: 'Yes', acPenalty: 'Yes' },
    { skill: 'Craft', skillMod: 'Dex', untrained: 'Yes', acPenalty: 'No' },
    { skill: 'Diplomacy', skillMod: 'Dex', untrained: 'Yes', acPenalty: 'No' }
]
```

And this is an example of a computed observable I tried.

```
self.AcrobaticsTotal = ko.computed(function() {
    return Number(self.AcrobaticsRanks()) + Number(self.dexMod()) + Number(self.AcrobaticsMod()) + Number(self.AcrobaticsTrained());
}, this);
```

I can get this all working if I hand code it, but I thought I would do it smartly and avoid typing all 40 skills and all of the associated observables. Thanks for any advice.

edit: I should have been more clear, I'm trying to get the data-bind to be the equivalent of other observables that I've declared.  I want eval($data.' + skill + 'Total') to be acrobaticsTotal and have ko act on the acrobaticsTotal observable.

Comment: You may need to post more javascript. You're not showing any of the observables that your computed is using.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using an eval() in the data-bind ... just use a function. Pass in the skill and the postfix that you want to call and then invoke that as a computed like so:

```
self.totalFor = function(skill, postfix) {
    var func = skill + postfix;

    // This will call the computed for the interpolated arguments
    return self[func]();
}
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/bryanray/ugfggo1r/4/

**UPDATE**

Added a textbox that allows you to change the 'acrobatics' value. The text box will then show the updated value. Hope that helps.

Updated to fix binding error for missing observables. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Thanks.  This is the answer but I can't quite get it to work.  Given: self.AcrobaticsRanks = ko.observable("0");, $root.totalFor($data.skill, 'Ranks') is not observable but if I hardcode it as $root.AcrobaticsRanks, it becomes observable.  Any ideas?

Comment: I love you guys for helping, however the examples include a hard coded input table.  The moment I change the hardcoded acrobatics into <input size="2" "type="text" data-bind="value: $parent.totalFor($data.skill, 'Ranks')" /> the Total does not change.